# Many to many xml relationship using spring giving same object in owner oject

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I have two tables user and dailyGame in which there are may-to-mapping. And I want to send following information in response to show daily game list:

- gameName
- format
- startTime
- fees
- member count (I want to get count from 3rd table ie. dailyGame_user.)

My user.hbm.xml file contains :

```
<set name="dailyGames" table="dailygame_user" 
        inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
        <key>
            <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.mindbowser.draftDynasty.dto.DailyGameDTO">
            <column name="groupId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

And DailyGame.hbm.xml :

```
    <set name="members" table="dailygame_user" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="gameId" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <many-to-many entity-name="com.mindbowser.draftDynasty.dto.UserDTO">
            <column name="userId" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
    </set>
```

UserDTO.java:
    `Set<DailyGameDTO> dailyGames  = new HashSet<DailyGameDTO>();`

DailyGameDTO.java:
    `Set<UserDTO> members = new HashSet<UserDTO>();`

And for fetching Daily game List I am using following code:
dailyGameDao:

```
public List<DailyGameDTO> getDailyGameList() {
    List<DailyGameDTO> gameList = null;
    DailyGameDTO dailyGameDTO=null;
    List<DailyGameDTO> memList=null;
    try {
        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(DailyGameDTO.class);
        gameList = criteria.list();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        logger.error(ex.getStackTrace(), ex);
        throw ex;
    }
    return gameList;
}
```

This "gameList" variable should consist userDTO object but it contains dailyGameDTO object only instead of userDTO .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change lazy="true"  to lazy="false".

Comment: Maybe your answer would be more useful if you added a small explanation WHY this should be done.